# How to add tags to post from frontend?

Tags: post-meta, tags

I am working on a site where visitors will be able to add tags to post from frontend without being able to edit the already assigned tags. It basically will be a add tag button where upon clicking opens a input field to add tags.

Is this possible. If yes, Please provide a direction in which I can achieve?

Thanks.

Comment: Use wp_set_post_tags() WP function

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to form action:

```
wp_set_post_tags( $post_ID, $tags, $append )
```

Function reference: [`wp_set_post_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_tags)